# sqlite.create returning null in Angular

Tags: angular, database, sqlite, ionic4

Below are my imports in my database.service.ts.

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SQLitePorter } from '@ionic-native/sqlite-porter/ngx';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Below is the constructor I am using to try to build the database.

```
  constructor(private plt: Platform, private sqlitePorter: SQLitePorter, private sqlite: SQLite, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      const conn = this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'emotions.db',
        location: 'default'
      });
      if (conn == null) throw Error('Failed to create database connection');
      conn.then(() => {
        console.log('Done');
      })
    });
  }
```

This is run when the app begins, and throws the statement I told it to because the conn == null in this case.

I am unsure why this is occurring, as there are no build errors when doing 'ionic serve'.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to get a response, just try the way of [ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite),

```
this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
})
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    console.log(db);
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still returns the same error. I am unsure why, but I don't know if the plugin hasn't been installed properly, but since there are no build errors this seems unlikely.

Comment: I suggest you remove and reinstall the plugin again.

Comment: I am using the same thing in my project and it's working absolutely fine.

Comment: as I am seeing you are using service for this, am I right?

Comment: I have done these commands:

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

npm install @ionic-native/sqlite

After this, it is still not working.

Comment: please replace it with my code and let me know the error or the thing is print in the console.

Comment: The error reads:


core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at database.service.ts:52

Comment: This means that the sqlite.create is returning NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208001/discussion-between-deepak-kumar-and-kickergold).

Comment: I also get this warning:

Native: tried accessing the SQLite plugin but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator